# Method to show a time series of ~300 values is not stationary

Tags: time-series, econometrics

I have a data series with approximatelly 300 values. I want to show that it is not **weakly** stationary, that is, show as mathematically as possible that its mean or its standard deviation vary with time.
What would you recommend? I would like to be capable of implementing it on excel.

Comment: What did you do finally? Would be glad to know.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply computing [moving averages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) (MA) and moving variances (MV) so as to compare them side-by-side, respectively performing [Welch's test for equality of means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test) and [F-test of equality of variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances).

E.g. the variance over the period $t:t+n$ with the one over $t+\ell:t+n+\ell$, where $n\in(0,299-t-\ell]$ is the MV window size, $\ell\in(0,299-t-n]$ is the time distance between the two compared periods (possibly overlapping, but imperfectly), and $t\in[0,299−n-\ell]$. An illustration below

[image]

The F-test (1) as well as Welch's test (2) are easily doable with excel (see, e.g. [(1)](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/f-test.html) and [(2)](http://www.real-statistics.com/students-t-distribution/two-sample-t-test-uequal-variances/)).

Comment: Any question @John ?